# Problemas em criar branchs -fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'. ; bash: id: No such file or directory

Tags: git

Comecei a usar git recentemente, criei um repositório local e um pequeno projeto, versionei e enviei para um repositório online, e nenhum problema ocorreu, porém, quando comecei a desenvolver outro projeto (claro, em um outro diretório), e ao versionar, um problema me apareceu, executei `git init` mas ao tentar criar uma branch me é devolvido esse aviso:

> fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.

(O nome da branch é um exemplo, esse erro ocorre com qualquer nome de branch que coloco) Eu consigo usar `git checkout -b master` e ele devolve o aviso `Switched to a new branch 'master'`, mas quando executo o comando `git branch` ele não me devolve uma lista de branchs, fica como se não tivesse criado uma branch, e quando tento `commit`, ele devolve o seguinte aviso:

> bash: id: No such file or directory.

Tentei `git add` antes de criar alguma branch, mas os mesmos "sintomas" ocorrem. Também tentei clonar um repositório online vazio para trabalhar nele, mas ainda assim não consigo criar branchs ou fazer commits. Peço a ajuda de vocês. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser??

Comment: Acontece isso se você der um nome sem espaços? Eu acho que não pode ter espaço em nome de branch

Comment: se executar `git remote -v` mostra o repositório remoto que está conectado?

Comment: Olá @RafaelTavares, boa tarde. Os nomes das branchs não possuem espaços, ocorre o erro em qualquer nomes como: master, Alter-1, A, B, e etc...

Comment: Olá @RicardoPontual, boa tarde. Sim, quando executo `git remote -v` ele me mostra o repositório remoto que estou.

Answer (score 1):

Nomes de branches não podem conter espaços. Ao invés de fazer `git checkout -b nome da branch`, faça `git checkout -b nome-da-branch`. Certifique-se também de que está com uma versão atualizada do Git.

Comment: Olá @ViniciusBrasil, boa noite. Todos os nomes que tentei não tinham espaços, ocorre o erro em qualquer nomes como: master, Alter-1, A, B, e etc... Obs.: o git está atualizado, baixei do site oficial a última versão.

Comment: Entendi. É que você colocou na pergunta `fatal: Not a valid object name: 'nome da branch'.`. Parece que estava usando `nome da branch` como nome. Edita a pergunta com todos os comandos git que você tá executando e o retorno de cada um?

Comment: Fiz as alterações.

Answer (score -3):

É importante verificar se foram adicionados arquivos com "git status";
Tive problema semelhante e bastou criar o commit para solucionar.
Veja em : https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/git-error-fatal-not-a-valid-object-name-master